EXCEL | Tabla dinámica con datos de tiempo aproximables
Buen día. ¿Cómo hago una tabal dinámica en Excel con datos de tiempo con fracciones de segundos? La BD está compuesta por 4 columnas [Prueba, Torneo, Fecha, Tiempo]. El formato del tiempo está personalizado tipo [h]:mm:ss.00.
La BD sí muestra las fracciones de segundos, pero la tabla dinámica no así le haya cambiado el formato de número.
Tabla Base Datos:

Tabla dinámica que no muestra las fracciones de segundos:


Pues parece ser un fallo en las tablas dinámicas pero no encuentro fuentes oficiales que lo confirmen.
He hecho una prueba con tabla dinámica y con SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO y los resultados en la tabla dinámica omiten los decimales mientras que con fórmula sí los lee:

Si vemos los detalles de cómo lee el tiempo la tabla dinámica, veremos que solo los lee como [hh]:mm:ss así que parece algún tipo de limitación de la propia tabla dinámica:

No obstante, con SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO todo se lee correctamente. Podrías usar esa aproximación.

Gracias por la alternativa. Automatizar ese proceso para una gráfica dinámica no se podría, o sí?

@Pablovick Automatizar casi seguro. Podrías crearte una tabla con los datos en bruto y que se vaya actualizando y luego un pequeño cuadro de mando con sumar.si.conjunto vinculado a dicha tabla de tal manera que se actualice cuando añadas datos a la tabla origen
